# Detecting how many different types of values in in an array

Tags: javascript

I know I could use variations of this answer to find out how many different types of data there are in an array:

[How to count the number of certain element in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120931/how-to-count-the-number-of-certain-element-in-an-array)

But, what I am looking for is whether there is a simple way to count how many different types of data there are in an array:

I have arrays which may have 0, 1, or 2 as values

so it could be:

```
a = [1,2,0,1,1,1];
```

or they may all be the same and a different length:

```
a = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1];
```

In javascript, I would like a function that returns "1" if all values are the same, "2" if there is a mixture of just two of the possible values, and if the array contains all three values, "3".

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple approach is to keep a map of found values, and remember every time you add to it: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ojipit/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/ojipit/1/edit)

```
function countUniques(a) {
    var valuesSeen = {};
    var count = 0;

    a.forEach(function(value) {
        if (!valuesSeen[value]) {
            ++count;
            valuesSeen[value] = true;
        }
    });
    return count;
}
```

*(Note: That uses ES5's `forEach`. If you're using an old browser, you'll need to shim that, search for "ES5 shim" to find a shim for it.)*

Or if you don't like the people you work with very much and love using operators instead of branching statements: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/ojipit/2) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/ojipit/2/edit)

```
function countUniques(a) {
    var valuesSeen = {}, count = 0;

    a.forEach(function(value) {
        valuesSeen[value] || (++count,  valuesSeen[value] = true);
    });
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Fastest typer in the world.. +1

Comment: There's gotta be a funkier solution using `.reduce` ;-)

Comment: @Alnitak: LOL! I'm sure. :-) Almost all solutions using `reduce` are funky.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder OK, it's _fairly_ funky ;-)

Comment: Worked a treat. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, here's a "funkier" (and somewhat obfuscated) solution using `.reduce` that requires no local variables:

```
function countUniques(a) {
     return a.reduce(function(p, v) {
         p.c += !(v in p.s); p.s[v] = 1; return p;
     }, {c:0, s:{}}).c;
}
```

It's functionally identical to TJC's answer, except that the `valuesSeen` and `count` values are passed around as an object `p` as the "previous" value passed from the prior iteration of `.reduce.`   The `p.c` element is equivalent to TJC's `count` and `p.s` is `valuesSeen`.

Note that `.reduce` (like `.forEach`) is an ES5 function which will require a shim on older browsers.

Comment: OMG that gets an upvote for entertainment value alone! And I thought my alternate using `||` and `,` was for "if you don't like the people you work with very much". No no no, *yours* is. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder functional programming courses 20+ years ago FTW ;-)

Comment: Just for fun another elusive way: `return p.c += p.s[v] = !(v in p.s), p;`.

Comment: @FelixKling really nice! :)  I was looking for a way to (ab)use the comma operator but hadn't found it yet.  It did take me a while to figure out how yours works given that unlike the original (and TJC's code) `p.s[v]` doesn't remain constant, until I realised that (of course) the `v in p.s` test doesn't care what the value is, only that the key exists.