# Looping and counting on arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have an array of objects with known keys.
And I want to count how many objects have a particular key with a certain value.
Currently I made it up with this:

```
counter = () => {
        if (Array) {
            let a = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < Array.length; i++) {
                if (Array[i].key === '1' || Array[i].key === '2' || Array[i].key === '3' || Array[i].key === '4' || Array[i].key === '5' || Array[i].key === '6' || Array[i].key === '7') {
                    a++;
                }
            }
            return a;
        }
    }
```

I tried reduce() and find() while converting arrays to objects and vice versa but with no luck yet.
I suppose there should be **more elegant way to perform such a simple task** in plain vanilla JS ES6 or ES7. Ideally a oneliner. No lodashing please.

All other questions here target searching in elements, when mine touch one level deeper.

Comment: post your array of object

Comment: what is `if(Array)` supposed to do?

Comment: `myArray.filter(item => item.someProp === value).length`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count the number of certain element in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120931/how-to-count-the-number-of-certain-element-in-an-array)

Comment: @smart-googler it indeed doesn't matter in this situation

Comment: @JonasWilms checking presence of an array

Comment: @smart-googler no that question differs in details

Comment: What is `b` in your code. You must post your array of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, here is that oneliner:

```
 array.reduce((count, el) => count + +["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"].includes(el.key), 0)
```

This uses `includes` to check wether `el.key` is one of the numbers, then the resulting boolean is turned into a number with the unary plus (true -> 1, false -> 0), and that is added to count for each element, resulting in the total count.

Comment: reduce() looks powerful, could you explain what's going on here?

Comment: @igniter added a short explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use the [javascript filter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter): Something like:

```
var count = array.filter(function(e){
                  return (e.key === '1' || e.key === '2' || e.key === '3' || e.key === '4' || e.key === '5' || e.key === '6' || e.key === '7')

}).length;
```

Basically, this filter your array of objects by the keys you want, at the end it calculates the array length.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `.filter()` fairly easily, like so:

The idea is that you want to filter down to only the objects that match, and then use a .length to get the count at the end. We can know if an element matches by checking if the object's `key` property value is included in the list of keys you are searching for.

```js
var test = [
{ key: '1' },
{ key: '3' },
{ key: '2' },
{ key: '7' },
{ key: '5' },
{ key: '8' },
]
var keysToSearch = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'];

function counter (objs, searchKeys) {
  return objs.filter(obj => searchKeys.includes(obj.key)).length;
}

console.log(counter(test, keysToSearch));
```

**EDIT**

Here's a solution that does the same thing as the above, but doesn't create a new array with  `.filter()`.

```js
var test = [
{ key: '1' },
{ key: '3' },
{ key: '2' },
{ key: '7' },
{ key: '5' },
{ key: '8' },
]
var keysToSearch = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'];

function counter (objs, searchKeys) {
  var count = 0;
  for (var obj of objs) {
    if (searchKeys.includes(obj.key)) { count++; }
  }
  return count;
}

console.log(counter(test, keysToSearch));
```

Comment: Why create a new array to do this?

Comment: @charlietfl which array are you referring to?

Comment: `filter()` returns new array. Also OP is starting with array of objects , not a single  object and also wants to match values

Comment: @charlietfl Oh I missed the array of objects part. I will fix. Also updated with an answer that creates no new arrays

Comment: @charlietfl Updated. I think I got it all now. Thank you for your comment, I didn't fully understand the question at first

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
var count = b.filter(element => {return element.key == requiredKey;}).length;
```

count will have the number of objects with same key

Answer (score 0):

Do not create new array, one line, loop on keys to reduce the loop iterations.

Reduce work like :

```
array.reduce((accumulator, oneArrayValue) => {
  // Function where treatment are done
  return theAccumulatorValueForNextLoopIteration;
}, initialValueOfTheAccumulator);
```

```js
function counter(obj, keys) {
  // void 0 equals undefined
  // So it's equivalent to typeof x !== 'undefined'

  // tmp is the accumulator, it's value is setted up at 0
  // then it becomes what you return after every loop
  return keys.reduce((tmp, x) => obj[x] !== void 0 ? tmp + 1 : tmp, 0);
}

console.log(counter({
  1: 'hey',
  2: 'how',
  8: 'you',
  12: 'doing',
  15: 'baguette',
}, [
  '1',
  '2',
  '3',
  '4',
  '5',
  '6',
  '7',
]));
```

Comment: Could you please explain what 1) 'void 0' and 2) 'tmp, 0' mean here in plain English?