# Array filter is not returning correct for Zero?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, filter

```js
function zeroCount(arr){       
   const zero = arr.filter(el=>{
            if(el===0){
                return el ;
            }
        });
    return zero.length ; // but it returns 0. I want it to return 3.
}

console.log(zeroCount([2,3,0,5,0,2,0]));
```

I want to return the no. of zero present in the array using filter.

Comment: `[2,3,0,5,0,2,0].filter(x=>x===0).length` ??

Comment: follow this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6120959/5703304

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function zeroCount(arr){       
   const zero = arr.filter(el=> el === 0);
   return zero.length;
}

console.log(zeroCount([2,3,0,5,0,2,0]));
```

Answer (score 2):

For filtering, you need to return a boolean like value, like a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) or [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value.

A better approach is to count zero values directly.

```js
function zeroCount(arr) {
    return arr.reduce((s, v) => s + !v, 0);
}

console.log(zeroCount([2, 3, 0, 5, 0, 2, 0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the logic as follows:

```
[....].filter(x => x===0).length
```

So your code will be

```js
    function zeroCount(arr){       
      return arr.filter(x => x===0).length;
    }
    
    console.log(zeroCount([2,3,0,5,0,2,0]));
```

The [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function. 
and [.length()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) will get the length of that array here.

Answer (score 0):

`filter` callback function should return boolean and you're not handling the false case

Your function should look like this

```
function zeroCount(arr){       
  const zero = arr.filter(el=>{
     return el === 0;
  });

  return zero.length; // it returns 3
}
```

or using shorthand

```
function zeroCount(arr){       
  const zero = arr.filter(el=> el === 0);

  return zero.length; // it returns 3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter will only add the element if you return a "truthy" value. Currently, you are returning e1, with is 0. (This is falsy).

Just return true instead.

```js
function zeroCount(arr) {
  const zero = arr.filter(el => {
    if (el === 0) {
      return true;
    }
  });
  return zero.length; // but it returns 0. I want it to return 3.
}

console.log(zeroCount([2, 3, 0, 5, 0, 2, 0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're returning 0 if the element is 0. How filter works is that is expects a boolean value on weither it should keep the current element in the new array.

The unlucky part here is that you're returning 0 which translates to false.

```js
function zeroCount(arr){       
   const zero = arr.filter(el=>{
            if(el===0){
                return el; // This returns 0 so it won't be added to the filtered array
            }
        });
    return zero.length ; // but it returns 0. I want it to return 3.
}

console.log(zeroCount([2,3,0,5,0,2,0]));
```

This would work

```js
function zeroCount(arr){       
   const zero = arr.filter(el=> el === 0); // if the element is 0 then el === 0 will resolve to true and the element will be added to the filer array
    return zero.length ; // returns 3
}

console.log(zeroCount([2,3,0,5,0,2,0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how the filter works.

the filter function will pick or remove elements based on your return true or false from inside.

you are returning el which is 0. 0 in JS is false. that's why your code doesn't work.

two possible solutions
1)

```
function zeroCount(arr){       
 const zero = arr.filter(el=>{
        if(el===0){
            return true ;
        }
    });
   return zero.length ; // but it returns 0. I want it to return 3.
 }
```

2)

```
function zeroCount(arr){       
  const zero = arr.filter(el=> !el);
  return zero.length ; // but it returns 0. I want it to return 3.
 }
```

3) to show off

```
zeroCount = (arr) => arr.filter(el => !el).length
```

Answer (score 0):

The handler for the function `filter` should return a boolean

*The following approach assumes there are only numbers.*

```js
function zeroCount(arr) {
  return arr.filter(el => !el).length;
}

console.log(zeroCount([2, 3, 0, 5, 0, 2, 0]));
```

The previous approach generates an unnecessary array, so, as you want to count, a better approach is using the function `reduce` as follow:

```js
function zeroCount(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((r, el) => r + !el, 0);
}

console.log(zeroCount([2, 3, 0, 5, 0, 2, 0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

The below method helps to return the count of the falsy values in the array.

```js
function zeroCount(arr){       
   return arr.filter(elem => !elem).length;
}

console.log(zeroCount([2,3,0,5,0,2,0]));
```