# Is there .count method in javascript like python?

Tags: javascript, arrays, count

In Python, if we have a list,

```py
array = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

If we say `array.count(1)`, it will return the count of 1 in `array`.

Is there a method like this in javascript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count the number of certain element in an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120931/how-to-count-the-number-of-certain-element-in-an-array)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting the occurrences / frequency of array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667888/counting-the-occurrences-frequency-of-array-elements)

Comment: `array.filter((x) => x === <value to match>).length`

Answer (score 2):

I think there isn't. But you can make one by using `prototype`.

```js
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,1];

Array.prototype.count = function(value) {
    let count = 0;

    this.forEach(item => {
 if (item === value) {
     count++;
 }
    });

    return count;
}

console.log(array.count(1));
console.log(array.count(2));
```