# Create Object of Arrays from multidimensional Array arranged by key types

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Following one of the answers of [How to count certain elements in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120931/how-to-count-certain-elements-in-array/61456846#61456846) created the *JavaScript* code below to build a *Object*, what can be used to build a *Object* named *chars* what can be used as `chars.str` and `chars.num`:

```js
    const arr="abrakadabra".split('');
    const counts = {};
    arr.forEach((el) => {
      counts[el] = counts[el] ? (counts[el] += 1) : 1;
    });
    const countsSorted = Object.entries(counts).sort(([_, b], [__, a]) => a - b);
    console.log(countsSorted); // [["a",5],["b",2],["r",2],["k",1],["d",1]]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

What is the elegant way to create *Object* from `countsSorted` what can be used as `chars.str` and `chars.num`, like:

```
Object {
  num: [5, 2, 2, 1, 1],
  str: ["a", "b", "r", "k", "d"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of [JavaScript Array of Objects Tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-array-of-objects-tutorial-how-to-create-update-and-loop-through-objects-using-js-array-methods/#add-a-property-to-every-object-of-an-array-array-foreach) I was able to understand more and have found the [JavaScript Array forEach() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp) as a solution. Working example below:

```js
    const arr="abrakadabra".split('');
    const counts = {};
    arr.forEach((el) => {
      counts[el] = counts[el] ? (counts[el] += 1) : 1;
    });
    const countsSorted = Object.entries(counts).sort(([_, b], [__, a]) => a - b);

    var chars = new Object();
    chars.str = [];
    chars.num = [];
    
    countsSorted.forEach((asd) => {
      chars.str.push(asd[0]);
      chars.num.push(asd[1]);
    });

    console.log(chars); // {"str":["a","b","r","k","d"],"num":[5,2,2,1,1]}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.reduce()` to transform arrays to objects:

```js
const str = "abrakadabra";

const countsSorted = Object.entries(
  str .split('').reduce((acc, el) => {
    acc[el] = (acc[el] ?? 0) + 1;

    return acc;
  }, {})
).sort(([, a], [, b]) => b - a);

const chars = countsSorted.reduce((acc, [str, num]) => {
  acc.str.push(str);
  acc.num.push(num);

  return acc;
}, { str: [], num: [] });

console.log(chars); // {"str":["a","b","r","k","d"],"num":[5,2,2,1,1]}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```