# trying to get a count from an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, count

hey guys new to javascript and trying to run a simple count procedure in arrays

i have built an array from some prompts and am now trying to run a loop through to count negative and positive numbers

i understand the for loop context, would i have to build another emtpy array and push results to it?

this is what i have written up so far...

```
let array2 = []
    for (let i = 0; i < numberCount; i++) {
        if (array[i] > 0) {
            i == 1
            array2.push(i)
        }
    }
```

any help appreciated, dont burn me to hard!

Comment: What are you hoping `i == 1` will do here?  I do not think it means what you think it means.

Comment: no worries, the idea is that the variable would equal the value of 1, definately understand im not doing it right, hoping for some insight as im trying to understand how the language works. cheers

Comment: If you are just counting, there is no need for another array. Just have 2 counters - one for negative and one for positive. `if (array[i] > 0) positiveCounter += 1;`

Comment: Consider `array.filter(n => n > 0).length`

Comment: oh ok cool to see both options, i tend to overthink and think my original solution may be a bit overkill

Comment: so from my understanding, the counter will increment 1 everytime the condition is met? does this make the counter the new variable?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120931/how-to-count-certain-elements-in-array

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code

```
let array = [0, 1, 2, -1, -4, 5, -12, -4]
let count = 0
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] < 0) {
        count = count + 1
    }

}
console.log(count)
```

Answer (score -1):

Please clear. what you want...

If you want to find the number of elements present in array , you can use `.length` property.

```
let array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
let arrayCount = array.length
```

Comment: it was more of gathering specific data based on an if statement, the counter function has worked for me right now. the idea was if an item in the array was < 0 then it would increment a count. Thanks for providing another look at the problem