# Array.filter returning no matches, possible issue with quotation marks in string?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects created by [us-parser-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ua-parser-js) that look like this:

```
{
  ua: '"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; Lenovo TB-X606F) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.75 Safari/537.36 ABB/3.1.0"',
  browser: { name: 'Chrome', version: '93.0.4577.75', major: '93' },
  engine: { name: 'Blink', version: '93.0.4577.75' },
  os: { name: 'Android', version: '10' },
  device: { vendor: 'Lenovo', model: 'TB-X606F', type: 'tablet' },
  cpu: { architecture: undefined }
}
```

I have a log file of user-agents that have visited a page:

```
-
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 11; SM-A415F Build/RP1A.200720.012; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/102.0.5005.125 Mobile Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; SM-A202F Build/PPR1.180610.011; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/103.0.5060.53 Mobile Safari/537.36
...
```

For each `ua` in the first array, I want to count how many times they appear in the file. I read the file into an array, with one line per entry, and then do this, cribbed from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72450849/11020164):

```
missingBrowsers.forEach((el, key, arr) => {
  arr[key].count = pageviews.filter(ua => ua === '"' + el.ua + '"').length;
});
```

But for some reason it adds a count of 0 in all cases, including the super simple one of just matching on a dash (-), as seen in the below snippet. I'm guessing it has something to do with the strings not matching because of the quotation marks, but if I add ubiquitous `console.log`s, everything looks to my eye like it should match, so maybe it's something to do with the filter.

```js
let missingBrowsers = [ {
  ua: '"-"',
  browser: { name: undefined, version: undefined, major: undefined },
  engine: { name: undefined, version: undefined },
  os: { name: undefined, version: undefined },
  device: { vendor: undefined, model: undefined, type: undefined },
  cpu: { architecture: undefined },
},
{
  ua: '"Mozilla/5.0 (Android 11; Mobile; rv:101.0) Gecko/101.0 Firefox/101.0"',
  browser: { name: 'Firefox', version: '101.0', major: '101' },
  engine: { name: 'Gecko', version: '101.0' },
  os: { name: 'Android', version: '11' },
  device: { vendor: undefined, model: undefined, type: 'mobile' },
  cpu: { architecture: undefined },
},
{
  ua: '"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; Lenovo TB-X606F) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.75 Safari/537.36 ABB/3.1.0"',
  browser: { name: 'Chrome', version: '93.0.4577.75', major: '93' },
  engine: { name: 'Blink', version: '93.0.4577.75' },
  os: { name: 'Android', version: '10' },
  device: { vendor: 'Lenovo', model: 'TB-X606F', type: 'tablet' },
  cpu: { architecture: undefined },
} ];

let pageviews = [ '-',
'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 11; SM-A415F Build/RP1A.200720.012; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/102.0.5005.125 Mobile Safari/537.36',
'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; SM-A202F Build/PPR1.180610.011; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/103.0.5060.53 Mobile Safari/537.36' ]

missingBrowsers.forEach((el, key, arr) => {
  arr[key].count = pageviews.filter(ua => ua === '"' + el.ua + '"').length;
});
console.log(missingBrowsers[0]);
```

Comment: `pageViews` doesn't have quotes surrounding the string content. The `missingBrowsers` does. So if you take an item from `pageViews` like `-` and ten check if it's equal to `""-""` then the result would be `false`.

Comment: You're concatenating the quotes to the wrong value. It should be `'"' + ua + '"' === el.ua`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're wrapping the wrong element in your `filter :

```
arr[key].count = pageviews.filter(ua => ua === '"' + el.ua + '"').length;
```

Should be:

```
arr[key].count = pageviews.filter(ua => '"' + ua + '"' === el.ua).length;
```

Comment: Why is this worth an answer? What's the value for future readers? Why is this not just a comment and a "just a typo" close-vote?

Comment: Because I felt this one had some actual effort put into writing the question, even if it's just gonna get closed.

Comment: FWIW, I'm totally ok with it being closed — would even do it myself if someone tells me how. But thanks for recognising the effort @Cerbrus :)

Comment: Turns out I cast the close-vote before Andreas did :D