# javascript querySelectorAll find text occurrences even if hidden

Tags: javascript

I have a table which I'm trying to extract the number of occurrences of a text match. The issue has sometimes the text is not visible in the table due to class="hide" so the queries I have tried are only returning the visible matches.

Example of what I have been trying is

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('td:nth-child(2)'))
  .find(el => el.textContent.trim() == 'AU2014280123A')
```

I have also tried innerHtml and other variations.

Below is the elements which show there are 2 matches but the query above is only returning one

[image]

Any ideas on how I can return all matches regardless if they are hidden or not?

Thanks

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. Are you trying to _include_ or _exclude_ hidden elements? Your current code should return all elements, regardless of classnames

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I'm trying to include all hidden elements. Ideally, I just want the count of matches. eg. 2 in this case so if there is another way to write the query then open to that as well

Comment: They are already included ~ https://jsfiddle.net/8mw5p9j7/

Comment: Your code uses [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) so why is it surprising that it only returns one item? Use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) if you want all the matches

Comment: When I run in console I only see one match

Comment: No kidding. That's what `find()` does... _"returns the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function"_

Comment: ok, thanks. how do I return the number of matches then?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to count certain elements in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6120931/283366)

Comment: yep, thanks. all good now. filter working